# Ruby: Can not read an attribute by self.attr

Tags: ruby, private-methods, attr-accessor

I am learning Ruby basic, and trying to do some tests. I encounter an issue to understand the class method accesss scope.

Here is my code.

```
class User

    attr_accessor :name

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @login_status = false
    end

    def login
        puts "user #{name} logged in"
        self.login_status = true
    end

    def logout
        puts "user #{name} logged out"
        self.login_status = false
    end

    def login?
        self.login_status
    end

    private

    attr_accessor :login_status

end
```

I got 'no such method error' when I had a test in irb

```
2.5.9 :001 > load 'user.rb'
 => true 
2.5.9 :002 > u = User.new 'Mike'
 => #<User:0x00007ff1a10eb358 @name="Mike", @login_status=false> 
2.5.9 :003 > u.login
user Mike logged in
 => true 
2.5.9 :004 > u.login?
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from /Users/sgao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.9/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        2: from (irb):3
        1: from user.rb:21:in `login?'
NoMethodError (private method `login_status' called for #<User:0x00007ff22f860938 @name="test", @login_status=false>)
2.5.9 :005 >
```

I am thinking why `self.login_status = true` works when I invoke `u.login`, but `self.login_status` fails when I invoke `u.login?`.

Comment: While experienced Rubyists will find the posted exception clear, this is actually **a good question** because the use of private methods in Ruby (and the uncommon practice of making accessors private) are quite likely to be non-intuitive and trip up anyone new to Ruby. The OP included code and the relevant exception, so I consider it an excellent first question.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

The way private methods work in a dynamic language like Ruby is a common source of confusion. In Ruby, private methods primarily work by disallowing an explicit receiver. The underlying problem in your code is that you've declared your accessor methods for `:login_status` as private for some reason. I explain more about the problem and the possible solutions below.

### How You Unintentionally Broke the Code

You did this to yourself by declaring the `:login_status` accessor as private. This prevents your public methods from calling it with an explicit receiver. Although you can still *read* the created instance variable of *@login_status* from your public methods as a sort of syntax sugar for the getter method—in Ruby 3.1.1, anyway; I didn't test it with anything else—you don't actually have direct access to the getter method, or an easily-accessible setter method for assigning to the instance variable.

[Module#attr_accessor](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) is just shorthand for declaring a pair of getter and setter methods on a object. When you place the accessor declaration after calling [Kernel#private](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Module.html#method-i-private), Ruby defines the #login_status and #login_status= getter and setter methods as *private* methods. You did that here:

```rb
private

attr_accessor :login_status
```

**In Ruby, you cannot call a private method with an explicit receiver.** Your exception even tells you that this is the problem (bold and emphasis mine):

> NoMethodError (***private method* `login_status' called** for #<User:0x00007ff22f860938 @name="test", @login_status=false>)

### Possible Fixes

#### Recommended Fixes

The best solution is probably to change your #login? method to use an implicit receiver by removing `self` as the explicit receiver:

```rb
def login?
  login_status
end
```

or make the accessor public rather than private.

#### Possible, Not Recommended: Fixing with Object#Send

Alternatively, you can also use [Object#send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send) to more explicitly call private methods. However, without understanding *why* you think an accessor (which is generally most useful when made part of the public interface) should be defined as a set of private methods, I find it hard to recommend that approach as a generic best practice.

##### Reasons Not to *Rely* on Private Methods

Unlike some other languages, Ruby private methods aren't really off-limits. As a result, the use of private or protected methods in Ruby is often more of a set of advisory usage guidelines, or an indication of semantic intent to differentiate code from the public interface, rather than a hard line that users of a class or method can't cross.

That doesn't mean you shouldn't *use* private methods in your code. It's just that using them, especially when declaring accessors, is a lot less common than in other languages because the use cases are often less about enforcement than they are about communicating programmer intent.

Comment: could you explain why 'self.login_status = true' worked when I invoked 'u.login'. I thought #login_status= was a private method as well, but it worked when I called it with an explicit receiver

Answer (score -2):

> I am thinking why `self.login_status = true` works when I invoke `u.login`, but `self.login_status` fails when I invoke `u.login?`.

For the exact reason that `u.login` works but `u.fobnicatefoobarbazqux` doesn't: one method is defined, the other isn't.

The method `User#login_status=` is defined (`attr_writer :login_status` does that for you), but `User#login_status` isn't. You need to define it.

[`Module#attr_writer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer) essentially looks more or less like this:

```ruby
class Module
  def attr_writer(*meths)
    meths.each do |meth|
      define_method(:"#{meth}=") do |val|
        instance_variable_set(:"@#{meth}", val)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong code. I did define the 'login_status' with 'attr_accessor'. And the error that I got was 'NoMethodError (private method `login_status' called for #<User:0x00007ff22f860938 @name="test", @login_status=false>)'

Comment: Please, don't change the question in a way that invalidates existing answers. It is considered rude because it wastes the time of the people who have already answered the question.